# Injection fails on components to deployed Tomcat server [Spring Boot]

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

When I try to deploy my `.war` project (Spring Boot) on a Tomcat server I get the following exception on the logs. Note that this exception doesn't happen locally, so I can only reproduce it on server enviroment.

Complete stacktrace https://pastebin.com/8uFqwk0U

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingComponent': Failed to introspect bean class [com.project.components.MappingComponent] for lookup method metadata: could not find class that it depends on; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/time/temporal/Temporal
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:269) ~[spring-beans-4.3.5.RELEASE.jar:4.3.5.RELEASE]
```

I searched of course about this issue and I've changed some dependencies on ton `pom.xml`, also removed and added constructors just in case but I couldn't figure out why this is happening.

`MappingComponent` the calss that exception happens

```
@Component
public class MappingComponent {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    Repository1 repo1;

    @Autowired
    Repository2 repo2;

    //no constructors
    //methods that are using the repositories

  }
```

`MappingController` the class that injects `MappingComponent`

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping("/services")
public class MappingController {

      @Autowired
      private ClientComponent clientComponent;

      @Autowired
      private MappingComponent mappingComponent;

      //no constructors
      //services that are using the components

 }
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>services</groupId>
    <artifactId>services</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>services</name>
    <description>Services</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>  
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

             <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <executions>
                              <execution>
                                <goals>
                                  <goal>repackage</goal>
                                </goals>
                              </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServicesApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ServicesApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I am aware that both java and spring are outdated, but it doesn't depend on me to upgrade them to a newer version. And that's not the issue because there are other services deployed with the same version (and identical pom.xml).

Comment: Temporal class has been introduced only in 1.8 and in your pom I see that you use 1.7.

Comment: Is it possible to get detailed stacktrace ? From the stacktrace the bean creation for MappingComponent is not happening because one of the autowired beans for the class is not getting resolved.Need to identify which bean is missing from the stacktrace.Since it's a repository bean it's possible that some initial setup for this environment is missing some values to create the bean.

Comment: @Ananthapadmanabhan I added a pastebin with the complete stacktrace

Comment: As @Mannekenpix said you need to change your JDK to 1.8 if you want to use Temporal and it seems that you do in MappingComponent Bean.

Comment: I get it, I will remove now temporal and come back to you if that was the issue.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I completely forgot Temporal wasn't a build in package or something, and I used it on purpose. @Mannekenpix if you want to add as an answer to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Temporal class has been introduced only in 1.8 and in your pom I see that you use 1.7.
When you are not sure of when a class has been introduced, just check in the Javadoc the @Since tag.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to external the external dependency jar into the lib directory of the Tomcat web server. First shutdown tomcat, add jar to the lib directory, and then startup tomcat.